# Console script tags garbling up non-html output (e.g. json) when in devMode

Tags: plugin-development, json

I have a plugin returning json from a controller action using `$this->returnJson(...)`.

Works great in production, but when `devMode = true`, the json is invalidated because Craft is still dumping the console debugging script at the end of the content.

What's the best way to avoid this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove these two logging routes from your plugin's init() method in your PluginHandlePlugin.php file:

```
craft()->log->removeRoute('WebLogRoute');
craft()->log->removeRoute('ProfileLogRoute');
```

That will prevent the extra logging and profiling information to be output in the browser's console when devMode is enabled.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Wouldn't you always want these removed when using methods like `returnJson`, or anything that explicitly returns non-html?

Comment: Entirely possible, I suppose.