# BaseController::returnJson & devMode interference

Tags: plugin-development, json

While developing an API for a client site I recognized that there was a  tag being returned after our JSON response (generated using BaseController's returnJson method).

I copy & pasted some of the output into The Google and found a reference to the *YII_DEBUG* constant. I checked the value (true) and assumed it was related to devMode. I turned off devMode for this environment and the extra code went away (and YII_DEBUG===false).

I don't suspect that this extra output is expected while using the returnJson() method but I need to get around this. Can I turn off devMode outside of the config file? I really only want to make an exception when calling this method.

Comment: The question has been answered but I'd love to hear from P&T on whether or not this may change in a future release

Comment: What exactly is the extra output? Is it a bunch of `console.log()` calls (the profiler info)?

Comment: Yup, that's correct. There are a bunch of console.log calls

Comment: Got it. Right now Craft will only hide those if it’s an Ajax request. Would make sense that it’s based on the MIME type instead, though.

Comment: I agree. I can't think of a situation where I would actually want that output in my JSON file :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. See Brad's response here to so this without messing with devMode: [Console script tags garbling up non-html output (e.g. json) when in devMode](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/488/console-script-tags-garbling-up-non-html-output-e-g-json-when-in-devmode)

It would be nice if this happened automatically when specifically outputting non-html, though.

Answer (score 3):

As of [Craft 2.2](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2579), Craft will now only add the logs to the response if the Content-Type header is going to be "text/html" or "application/xhtml+xml". Should solve this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off dev mode for just this page/call if you'd like, using the [`config->set` API method](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/configservice#set).

```
craft()->config->set('devMode', false);
```

Don't forget to turn it back on after your function runs (if it still matters at that point).

Comment: Thank you! I'm setting devMode=false right before calling the BaseController::returnJson method. This is okay because the returnJson method spins down craft with craft->end() after echo'ing the json encoded data.