# Is it possible to disable dev output in a template when devMode is true?

Tags: templating, javascript, devmode

For example the template just outputs JSON, which breaks when Craft's devMode logging is added.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to disable the debugging output from the template, but if you use the header tag to explicitly set the document's content type to JSON, Craft wont output the debug data:

```{% header "Content-Type: application/json" %}```

Comment: Thanks Mats - worked fine. Do you want to create an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: That's great – I added an answer, thanks for following up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't disable the debugging output using Twig/templates.

However, Craft will only render the debug data if your document' Content-type header is either "text/html" or "application/xhtml+xml" ([source](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2294/1098)).

This means that if you're outputting JSON, you can set the template's Content-type to "application/json" (using Craft's [header tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/tags#header)), preventing Craft from dumping the debug data to the response:

```
{% header "Content-Type: application/json" %}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create a simple plugin with an `init()` method like so:

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->log->removeRoute('WebLogRoute');
    craft()->log->removeRoute('ProfileLogRoute');
}
```

That will prevent the extra logging and profiling information to be output in the browser's console when devMode is enabled.

Comment: Thanks Brad - good to know. Setting the Content-Type was enough in the end, at least for this particular scenario.

Comment: I putt this on github if people are feeling lazy: https://github.com/crswll/silence