# How to turn off application log in dev mode

Tags: devmode

I have been searching through the admin panel on our staging site trying to find where to turn off the application log.

I know that you can turn off dev mode, and that will turn off the log, but I still want dev mode on, I just want to turn off the log itself.

I did look at the documentation [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings) and was not able to find it.

Any suggestions.

Comment: You want to disable all logging to `craft/storage/runtime/logs`?

Comment: I want to disable that log that shows at the end of the page, it shows as application log in the console,

Comment: @BradBell Probably the application and profiling logs which are output in the front end. [This is the only way](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/489/1098), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifting from [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/489/1098) to a similar question:

You'll have to write a simple, custom plugin, and add the following to the `init()` method in your plugin's primary class:

```
craft()->log->removeRoute('WebLogRoute');
craft()->log->removeRoute('ProfileLogRoute');
```

For instant success, you can scaffold your plugin by visiting [the plugin factory](https://pluginfactory.io/) – name it whatever you want and don't enable any components.